# How to stop a build in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio, how do I stop a build?

> The build must be stopped before the solution can be closed.

[image]

I found this article on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399140.aspx but it's about Team Fortress Server rather than Visual Studio

Comment: Freudian slip on the "Team Fortress Server"? :-)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In the main menu click Build -> Cancel

Comment: Thanks. I love such accurate answers without any unnecessary information.

Comment: Frankly simple answer 

Comment: @JohnWales, accurate answers that do not answer the question with an annoying question! (Look, if you need more information, you probably can't be of much help...)

Answer (score 21):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> or Build -> Cancel in the menu

Comment: Thanks for the CTRL+Break, my menus were not responding!

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Break works mostly. In some keyboard 'Break' key may only have the wording 'Pause'.

In case the build is 'Queued', Right-click an in-progress build definition name in the Queued tab of Build Explorer, and then click Stop on the drop-down menu.
Alternately, you can click the Stop icon in the toolbar of the Queued tab of Build Explorer.

[MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399140(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I had this trouble on a .NET MAUI project in VS 2022, and it would not stop with the ctrl+break, or the Build > Cancel menu item. Here was how I found I could clear it-

1. Open Task Manager (right click on task bar and click 'Task Manager')
2. On the Processes tab find the Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 process, and click the chevron next to it to expand
3. Right click on each MSBuild.exe instance running under VS, and click 'End task'

This should pull VS out of being in the build state (screenshot below)-
[image]